# MacBook mouse control keys at login

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

Hoping this saves some time for someone and avoids frustration. Yesterday after rebooting my MacBook M1 (2021 with Ventura OS 12.0.1), I was not able to use certain keys (7, 8, 9, U, O, J, K, L) on the keyboard to enter my password. I was stuck as I was on the login screen. I spent 30-40 min searching for a solution using my phone. Though others have faced the issue, none of the suggestions work. I tried:

Pressing the touch button five times or Option-Cmd-F5 worked as I was on login screen.
There is no option to go to the settings
Booted in safe mode
Magic keyboard and In-built keyboard, both had the same behavior
I called Apple support and the lady was very helpful but she also couldn't find a solution. Details of mouse keys are here: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-the-pointer-using-mouse-keys-mh27469/mac

BTW, I didn't enable the mouse keys in the settings. Once I logged in, I double-checked and the mouse keys were not enabled. So it is a bug. I have a ticket but could not reproduce it to update the ticket at Apple.

Comment: Check if you have it set to press Opt 5 times to toggle [in Accessibility prefs, not Keyboard prefs]. I've never known it happen at login, so idk if that would work. Also, check once it's toggled it stays that way for next time.

Comment: I tried searching and didn't find it in Accessibility. I looked at all the sub-options. I am running Ventura.

Comment: Ah, I looked at your linked page again, it's TouchID*3 now, not Opt*5

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found was plugging in a USB keyboard and typing my password. USB keyboard was not using the shortcut.

Once I could log in, I checked and the mouse keys were not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Mouse Keys Option in Preferences->LockScreen->Accessibility:

I found the problem in my case: Mouse Keys was enabled in System Preferences -> LockScreen -> Accessibility. Once disabled, the issue was gone. Hope that helps.